# Save data in separate objects from same class

Tags: java, object, graphics, japplet

So I'm trying to make a boardgame where I have a player class. In this class I want to save different things, such as the position on the board, amount of money etc.

Problem is, when I try to make two players walk across the board. It adds up both values from the movePlayer method and moves up 10 spaces.

Am I missing something obvious here?

```
public class Board extends Component {
private Player playerOne;
private Player playerTwo;
public Board(){
    playerOne = new Player();
    playerTwo = new Player();
}

    g.fillOval(playerOne.getPositionX(), playerOne.getPositionY(), 50, 15); // draw player 1

    g.fillOval(playerTwo.getPositionX(), playerTwo.getPositionY(), 15, 50); // draw player 2

}

public  void rollDice(){
    playerOne.movePlayer(8);  // move player1 > 8 spots
    playerTwo.movePlayer(2); // move player2 > 2 spots            
}
}
```

movePlayer method, and all associated with it:

```
public static void updatePlayerPos(int x){
    if (playerPos > 40){
        playerPos = 2;
    } else {
        playerPos = playerPos + x;
    }
}

public static void changePosition(){
    if (playerPos < 12){
        positionX = positionX - 50;
    }else if(playerPos < 22){
        positionY = positionY - 50;   
    } else if (playerPos < 32){
        positionX = positionX + 50;
    }else if(playerPos < 42){
        positionY = positionY + 50;   
    }
}

public void movePlayer(int dicerolls){  
    for (int i = 0;i < dicerolls;i++){
        updatePlayerPos(1);
        changePosition();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show implementation of your movePlayer() ?

Comment: Ksven is correct.  We need to see Player.movePlayer.  The issue sounds like it is possible you are using a static variable to contain how far a player moved and thus invoking it on either player updates both.

Comment: You're right. The instance variables were static. /facepalm

Comment: Would be nice if someone also explains why he/she downvotes....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ChangePosition method is static and modifies some static variables. That means that you don't have the coordinates safed for every player, but they all share the same, hence the two methods add up. You need to declare the coordinates without the static modifier to make them fields that are individual on every instance of that class.